# How to unload a PHP array in a tree format?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got that array that is based on the user 1014. So like a pyramid I would like to echo a tree with the users that come that come after 1014 respectively.

Like:

```
$arr = array(

        1005 => 1014,
        1008 => 1014,

        1019 => 1008,
        1020 => 1008,
        1022 => 1005,
        1023 => 1005,
        );
```

1014
    - 1005
    - 1022 (this should indent more than the 1005)
    - 1023 (this should indent more than the 1005)
    - 1008
    - 1019 (this should indent more than the 1008)
    - 1020 (this should indent more than the 1008)

1005 and 1008 came from 1014
1019 and 1020 came from 1008
1022 and 1023 came from 1005

And so on...

I've created a function to go from the user id to the top but no idea the oposite...

```
function get_rede($id_winner) {

global $link;

$precednt = array();
$precednt_id = array();

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT rede FROM users WHERE id = '$id_winner' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);   
$rede = $row[0]; 

array_push($precednt, $rede);
array_push($precednt_id, $id_winner);

do {

$q_precednt = end($precednt); 

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT rede FROM users WHERE id = '$q_precednt' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);   
$rede = $row[0]; 

array_push($precednt, $rede);
array_push($precednt_id, $q_precednt);

}
while($rede != 1000);

return array($precednt,$precednt_id);
}
```

Thank you!

Well, that's the result I am after. Can't think of an array function to help me out.

[image]

Comment: Your question hurts my brain, it is very hard to read. Please try to much more specific. And be more specfic about which *part* does not work. Do not just throw a wall of code

Comment: Ronni, sorry for hurting your brain! It is so hard for me to format stackoverflow style... I just do not have a code for that, can't think of any...

Comment: I'm still not sure how you're trying to format what you've got there -- but I'm getting a kick how everyone is under 1014, aka 10-14 -- 

but, at any rate, \t is the character for "tab" - so that may help...

Comment: The current user is 1014, thats his tree of connected users. I need then a full tree of his connections.

Comment: If you can't figure out basic Markdown then you're going to struggle with recursion!

Comment: @Light I struggle with most things I do and I am quite happy about that. I just don't wanna waste time with basic markdowns that could be simpler.

Comment: @LeandroCintrao: Not bothering wastes _our_ time, which is not a good start when asking us for free help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you haven't been constructive. Why you here for? You have a recursive answer?

Comment: @LeandroCintrao: If I can help mould you into the sort of well-behaved Stack Overflow citizen who bothers to format his posts, then that will be _very_ constructive. This isn't your free personal helpdesk. It's a community.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
        1014 => 1003, 
        1003 => 1002, 
        1002 => 1000, 

        1005 => 1014,
        1008 => 1014,

        1019 => 1008,
        1020 => 1008,
        1022 => 1005,
        1023 => 1005,
        );

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new_arr[$value][$key] = 1;
}

ksort($new_arr);

// here is your output 
$output = reorder($new_arr);

function reorder($new_arr)
{
    if (count($new_arr) == 1) return $new_arr;
    $tree_array = $new_arr;
    foreach ($new_arr as $key => $values) {
        foreach (array_keys($values) as $ak) {
            if (array_key_exists($ak, $new_arr)) {

                $values[$ak] = $new_arr[$ak];

                $tree_array[$key] = $values;
                unset($tree_array[$ak]);
            }
        }   
    }

    return reorder($tree_array);
}
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [1000] => Array
        (
            [1002] => Array
                (
                    [1003] => Array
                        (
                            [1014] => Array
                                (
                                    [1005] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1022] => 1
                                            [1023] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1008] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1019] => 1
                                            [1020] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This assumes that you have one root.

Comment: Raj, I really appreciate your approach but this array may go far to 100 users deep. So if you add the other 4 1023 to the array it will not show up. Thank you

Comment: i assumed from your sample input, it didn't. you probably would need to do something recursive. let me see if i can give another snippet

Comment: Raj, I thought you'd got it! Unfortunately when I add to the array like $arr = array(  
        1005 => 1014,  
        1008 => 1014,  

        1019 => 1008,  
        1020 => 1008,  
  
        1022 => 1005,  
        1023 => 1005,  
  
        1031 => 1023,  
        1032 => 1023,  
        1033 => 1023,  
        1034 => 1023,  
        );  I don't get all users...

Comment: sorry about that, that should hopefully get you started

Comment: Nice one Raj! Will think about using mysql to sort that! Thank you anyway!